# How Does 3rd Party Component Licensing work in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, licensing, components, controls

In WinForms whole licensing schema in .NET is revolved around `LicenseManager` and `LicenseProvider` as mentioned quite nicely in [this article](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3074001/Applications-Licensing-using-the-NET-Framework.htm).

I have simple test form in WinForm (dropped licensed DevExpress's ButtonEdit in there) using below code I can see that it is getting license info fine:

`var license = LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(ButtonEdit), this);`

I can also see that it has auto generated licenses.licx file and added to my project.

So, I have tried to the same by dropping DevExpress/Telerik WPF controls into my sample WPF Window and I can see that licenses.licx file is NOT auto generated.

So If I try to run the same line in the WPF, `license` is returning null. That means that it is not using whole LicenseManager architecture in WPF.

What is it using then to check license for 3rd party component?

Looks like someone reported a [bug in VS 2010 in regards to this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/491013/wpf-licenses-licx-file-isnt-added-when-a-custom-licensed-control-is-dropped-onto-a-windows-designer), but I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

WPF also uses the same mechanism. You simply need to apply the **LicenseProvider** attribute to your class.

The licx file may not be generated in your project due to some other reason.

Comment: not quite sure, why LicenceManager didnt pickup the license for DevExpress/Telerik WPF Controls like it did for WinForms ones ?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that one of the 3rd party controls  (Telerik) that I have used for testing [works without license keys](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-premium-collection-for-dotnet.aspx) (scroll  to "How do you license your Developer licenses?" section).

Checking DevExpress and raised support ticket to Telerik and they have confirmed that they dont use licx for WPF Controls.